# Hide and Remove Admob banner

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, admob, cocos2d-x

I have developed a game in `cocos2dx` for iOS.Now i integrated banner view for show `admob` banner ad.
i write code for `admob` in `appController` class like that.

```
NSLog(@"ADMOB");
CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector]winSize];
bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc]
               initWithFrame:CGRectMake(size.width/2-160,
                                        size.height -
                                        GAD_SIZE_320x50.height,
                                        GAD_SIZE_320x50.width,
                                        GAD_SIZE_320x50.height)];
bannerView_.adUnitID =@"a*******";
bannerView_.delegate=self;
[viewController.view bannerView_];
bannerView_.rootViewController = viewController;
[bannerView_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
GADRequest request = [[GADRequest alloc] init];
request.testing =  [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                    GAD_SIMULATOR_ID, nil];
[bannerView_ loadRequest:request];
```

Now I have to hide or remove `admob` banner ad from `cpp` class. So I have to call C++ class to objective. C++ call and then call to `appcontroller` class. and suppose to de remove banner view like that

```
[bannerView removeFromSuperview];
[bannerView setDelegate:nil];
[bannerView release];
bannerView = nil;
```

but banner view not removing from that call.
please help me to getting out from this issues.
any help will be appreciated.

Comment: have you figured it out?

Answer (score 0):

Is your ad getting displayed properly,
since this line does nothing:-

```
[viewController.view bannerView_];
```

Shouldn't be this like

```
[viewController.view addSubview:bannerView_];
```